# SharePoint 2007 Preventing Funky Characters in Web.Config

Tags: 2007, web-config

We're not exactly sure what's causing this issue but our web.config in one of our Shared Services Providers just appeared to randomly have several funky "square like" characters. Does anyone know why this problem is caused and how to solve it?

Your thoughts and ideas are welcomed and likely will be rewarded with various clicks on arrows pointing upwards yet only one will recieve a checkmark.

Comment: Did the encoding get changed from UTF-8 to something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has someone been editing it in wordpad? Config files are UTF-8 and you're probably describing a character that is not in this set...

Richer text editors sometimes replace things (such as replacing quotes with a curly representation that is actually another character altogether).  Is there any indication as to what the characters should be?